# Add new elements in a Table View JavaFx dynamically

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-8

Guys this is the code I use to add elements in a Table View when the button `theButton` is pressed.

The Table View is filled with elements taken from the web, so to fill the whole Table View takes about 30 seconds...

I would like to add all the data dynamically, not wanting for all the data to put into the Table will be ready. So now it happens that when the button is pressed, it takes 30 seconds or so to display the results. This is my code, is there something wrong with it? Thank you.

```
theButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler() 
{
        @Override
        public void handle(Event event) 
        {                       

            try
            {
                ObservableList<Elements> toShow = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

                ArrayList<String> strings = takeSomeStrings();

                for (int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++) 
                {   
                    toShow.add(new Elements(takeInfoFromTheWeb(strings.get(i)))); 

                     myTableView.setItems(toShow);
                 }

                 } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                 {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
              }
         }
    }
```

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer as to what is happening and what you want? If the data takes 30 seconds to retrieve, it takes 30 seconds to retrieve, and no programming is going to change that. Are you wanting each item to be added independently as it is retrieved? Do you care about the order? Or do you just want all the items to be added but the UI to remain responsive in the meantime?

Comment: Exactly, when the button is pressed I want that the list will be created step by step. When the first result (the first element of the list) is ready, I want it to see it in the table. But now it does not happen that. When the button is pressed, nothing happens since everything is taken from the web. After 30 seconds I see the whole list complete. Of corse the order is not needed.

Comment: as an aside (unrelated to the required asynchronous filling of the data): there's no need to call table.setItems(..) in each iteration - the list is observable and the table is listening to its changes (f.i. additions of rows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an *executor* that fetches the data from the Web in background. Once fetched, use `Platform.runLater()` to modify the TableView on the JavaFX application thread.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

private final Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

theButton.setOnAction(event ->
{
    try
    {
        ObservableList<Elements> toShow = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        myTableView.setItems(toShow);

        ArrayList<String> strings = takeSomeStrings();

        for (String s: strings)
        {
            executor.execute(() -> {
                Elements el = new Elements(takeInfoFromTheWeb(s));
                Platform.runLater(() -> toShow.add(el));
            });
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

If you want to fetch the data in parallel, just replace the executor, e.g.

```
private final Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
```

And you will be downloading up to 4 items in parallel.

Comment: In layman's terms does this load and add items to the TableView, so that the user sees the table being updated in real time?